# Discord.JS music

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I've made commands for my bot to leave and join a voice channel now I need a command in which I can make my bot play the first result from a YouTube search. So basically Groovy Bot or Rythm Bot.
Here is an example of how I've done my other commands with my main file being:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = "!";

const fs = require("fs");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands/")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ani Bot is online!");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "marco") {
    client.commands.get("marco").execute(message, args);
  } else if (command === "mute") {
    client.commands.get("mute").execute(message, args);
  } else if (command === "unmute") {
    client.commands.get("unmute").execute(message, args);
  }
});
```

and an example of a command being:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "mute",
  description: "mutes the mentioned user",

  execute(message, args) {
    const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("751757808432709644");
    const target = message.mentions.members.first();

    target.roles.add(mutedRole);
    message.channel.send("Muted " + target + " ✅");
  },
};
```

Please help and a code explanation would be appreciated but just giving methods and pakages and stuff like that will be sufficient too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [yt-search](https://npmjs.com/package/yt-search) and [ytdl](https://npmjs.com/package/ytdl) for playing yt videos

Here is an example how can you do it -

```js
const yts = require('yt-search')
module.exports = {
  name: "search",
  description: "searches a yt video",

  async execute(message, args) {
   const res = await yts(args.join(" "))
   let video = res[0] //getting the first video
   // assuming that you are using discord.js v12
   let connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join()
   connection.play(ytdl(video.url))
 },
};
```